# How can this class be designed better?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

We have a Web API library, that calls into a Business/Service library(where our business logic is located), which in turn calls a Data access library (Repository).

We use this type of data transfer object all over the place.  It has a "Payers" property that we may have to filter (meaning, manipulate its value). I have gone about implementing that check as such, but it feels dirty to me, as I'm calling the same function all over the place.  I have thought about either:

1. Using an attribute filter to handle this or
2. Making the RequestData a property on the class, and do the filtering in the constructor.

Any additional thoughts or design patterns where this could be designed more efficiently:

```
public class Example
{
    private MyRepository _repo = new MyRepository();

    private void FilterRequestData(RequestData data)
    {
        //will call into another class that may or may not alter RequestData.Payers
    }

    public List<ReturnData> GetMyDataExample1(RequestData data)
    {
        FilterRequestData(RequestData data);
        return _repo.GetMyDataExample1(data);
    } 

    public List<ReturnData> GetMyDataExample2(RequestData data)
    {
        FilterRequestData(RequestData data);
        return _repo.GetMyDataExample2(data);
    } 

    public List<ReturnData> GetMyDataExample3(RequestData data)
    {
        FilterRequestData(RequestData data);
        return _repo.GetMyDataExample3(data);
    } 
}


public class RequestData
{
    List<string> Payers {get;set;}  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of dealing with repeated code like that is to use a strategy pattern with a Func (and potentially some generics depending on your specific case). You could refactor that into separate classes and everything but the basic idea looks like that:

```
public class MyRepository
{
    internal List<ReturnData> GetMyDataExample1(RequestData arg) { return new List<ReturnData>(); }
    internal List<ReturnData> GetMyDataExample2(RequestData arg) { return new List<ReturnData>(); }
    internal List<ReturnData> GetMyDataExample3(RequestData arg) { return new List<ReturnData>();  }
}

public class ReturnData { }

public class Example
{
    private MyRepository _repo = new MyRepository();

    private List<ReturnData> FilterRequestDataAndExecute(RequestData data, Func<RequestData, List<ReturnData>> action)
    {
        // call into another class that may or may not alter RequestData.Payers
        // and then execute the actual code, potentially with some standardized exception management around it
        // or logging or anything else really that would otherwise be repeated
        return action(data);
    }

    public List<ReturnData> GetMyDataExample1(RequestData data)
    {
        // call the shared filtering/logging/exception mgmt/whatever code and pass some additional code to execute
        return FilterRequestDataAndExecute(data, _repo.GetMyDataExample1);
    }

    public List<ReturnData> GetMyDataExample2(RequestData data)
    {
        // call the shared filtering/logging/exception mgmt/whatever code and pass some additional code to execute
        return FilterRequestDataAndExecute(data, _repo.GetMyDataExample2);
    }

    public List<ReturnData> GetMyDataExample3(RequestData data)
    {
        // call the shared filtering/logging/exception mgmt/whatever code and pass some additional code to execute
        return FilterRequestDataAndExecute(data, _repo.GetMyDataExample3);
    }
}

public class RequestData
{
    List<string> Payers { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This sort of thinking naturally leads to [aspect oriented programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming).
It's specifically designed to handle cross-cutting concerns (e.g. here, your filter function cuts across your query logic.)

As @dnickless suggests, you can do this in an ad-hoc way by refactoring your calls to remove the duplicated code.

More general solutions exist, such as [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/aspects) which give you a slightly cleaner way of structuring code along aspects. It is proprietary, but I believe the free tier gives enough to investigate an example like this. At the very least it's interesting to see how it would look in PostSharp, and whether you think it improves it at all! (It makes strong use of attributes, which  extends first suggestion.)

(N.B. I'm not practically suggesting installing another library for a simple case like this, but highlighting how these types of problems might be examined in general.)